# Views, if image field exists show it, else show this

Tags: 7, views

I was wondering if this this possible using Views with Views conditional.

I need to check whether an image field has content, and if not just show some html + a token from a computed field.

Which condition should I use in Views Conditions? And is it possible. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Rewrite the output of this field", can put an token inside the output and if I'm not wrong there's an check-mark "if the field has values".

Answer (score 0):

The "NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR" gives you a text box where you can enter something like "No image."

You can also set up the field in your content type so that there is a default image. That way, if no image has been included, your default image will show up in your view automatically, and you won't have to use "REWRITE RESULTS" or "NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR."